# Push does not work on javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add in a string array some data when a score taken from radio button is higher than a certain amount without using any type of loop but it seem that the push method does not work.
This is my javascript code:

```
var diet1 = 10, diet2 = 3 , diet3 =10 , diet4 = 15;
var message = new Array();
totalScore = diet1 + diet2 + diet3 + diet4;

if(totalScore > 25){
    if(age == 10){
        message = highRisk.push("a");
    }

    if(bmi == 10){
        message = highRisk.push("b");
    }

    if(history == 10){
        message = message.push("c");
    }

    if(age == 10){
        message = message.push("d");
    }
}
```

How do I add String Array item without loop? and also how do to reset the form once the user hit the submit button?.

Comment: `push` **is an in place operation**. Arrays are mutable, `push` does not return the updated array, but the new array length. Do not reassign.

Comment: Where does `highRisk` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need to do this :

```
message = message.push('a');
```

You only do this :

```
message.push('a')
```

Your code will be like this :

```
var diet1 = 10, diet2 = 3 , diet3 =10 , diet4 = 15;
var message = new Array();
totalScore = diet1 + diet2 + diet3 + diet4;

  if(totalScore > 25){
     if(age == 10){
        highRisk.push("a");
     }

    if(bmi == 10){
        highRisk.push("b");
   }

   if(history == 10){
     message.push("c");
   }

    if(age == 10){
       message.push("d");
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `message.push("a");`, instead of `message = highRisk.push("a");`.

Comment: @AndrewLi, yes, the syntax isn't wrong, but the code is wrong, if OP is trying to push `"a"` to `message` array.